# "Pivoting" a part while moving faces

Tags: modeling

Still a newbie to Blender. Trying to line the gray tube along the edge of the blue object, but there is still a slight lip. How do I rotate or pivot or whatever the gray tube so that it follows the edge of the blue object?
[image: Edge]

Comment: Maybe using bezier curves would be easier to fit your mesh

Answer (score 1):

This *may* not apply in your case, but it would be much easier to copy than to follow:

[image]

- Select the perimeter of your shape
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it and <kbd>P</kbd> part it off into a new object
- Header Menu *> Object > Convert to > Curve*
- Adjust the curve's bevel in its Data tab > Geometry panel

Convert back to mesh if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Combine a circle with a semicircle.

Set pivot, cursor, at the end of the semicircle and spin everything 180 deg.

Set origin to cursor and use Mirror modifier.